# Is it wrong to use sufficent statistc estimated from the data as a prior in Bayesian data analysis?

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, empirical-bayes

First I want to state that I got unexpected feedback from a reviewer in regard to my question and I am simply interested in others' views in this regard (I have already sent in my rebuttal).

Suppose that we have $N$ observations of the random variable $Y$ and we know that they are iid. In addition, we believe them to be normally distributed. As such we have the following model:
$$Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$$
Now, let's assume that $\sigma$ is known and for simplicity equal to 1.
We then have a sample of $Y$, $y$.
Now, if we assume the following model:
$$y \sim N(\mu,1)$$
$$\mu \sim N(\mu_o+\eta\sigma_\mu,\sigma_\mu)$$
$$\eta\sim N(0,1)$$
and suppose that $\sigma_\mu$ is known.
My question is: would it be circular to assume that $\mu_0=\bar{y}$?
That is, we assume that mean of our prior on the mean is the observed sample mean.
To me, it would seem like the sufficient statistic of $\mu$ would maximize the likelihood, but I am not sure. What are others' opinions?

Edit: also, in my actual model, the prior on the variance inhibits a closed form solution. But I tried to simplify things.

Comment: As a general rule, a Bayesian prior should be chosen before you see the data.  Otherwise both your prior and your likelihood are being driven by the data and you risk over-concentrating your posterior distribution

Comment: Yes, setting $\mu_0=\bar y$ is absolutely circular. Based on what you have said here, the reviewer is correct to say that your approach is not statistically valid. It is possible to esimate prior distributions from the data in empirical Bayes approaches, but EB cannot be done with one $\mu$ and one sample as you are doing here.

Comment: @GordonSmyth That looks like an answer to me!

Comment: @Dave OK, thanks, I've copied my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, setting $\mu_0=\bar y$ absolutely is circular.
The Bayesian model cannot be justified unless you genuinely do have information about $\mu$ that is separate to the data.
Based on what you have said here, the reviewer is correct to say that your approach is not statistically valid.
You will be overstating the amount of data information that you have because you entering the same data twice, once as the prior mean and once as the observed mean.

It is possible in some contexts to estimate prior distributions from the data using empirical Bayes approaches, but empirical Bayes cannot be done with one sample in isolation as you are doing here.

Comment: So, it would have been valid to, e.g., use a regression model to estimate the prior? If I have some other variable(s) X that I can use to predict the mean of several y samples?

Comment: @Baraliuh If you have many samples and many different $\mu$s, $\mu_i$ for sample $i$, then you can use the other samples (other than $i$) to create a prior for each $\mu_i$. That can be done with or without a covariate, with or without regression. See for example http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/ebayes.pdf or https://doi.org/10.1214/16-aoas920.

Comment: Ok thank you for the references. I've tried putting a uniform prior on my $\mu$ but it drastically reduces the model's performance compared to using $\bar{y}$. I do have several $\mu_{ij}$ from different and repeated experiments. I have already managed to generate an Empirical Bayes model for the hyper-parameter estimation of the prior of $\sigma$ and I am hoping to retain my model's current performance but remove circular reasoning. Thank you very much for your feedback, answer, and references.

Comment: @Baraliuh I don't know the details of your problem but it will probably be impossible to retain your model's current performance because setting the prior to the data and then measuring the accuracy of your model relative to the same data is, frankly, a type of cheating. Valid methods will not perform as well because the current performance is probably artificial. On the other hand, using a uniform prior for a normal mean would be jumping from one extreme to the other and would perform unnecessarily badly.

Comment: You are probably right. My model is definitely more complicated than this example and is trying to estimate the distribution of differences in $\mu_{ij}$s with HMC (due to no closed-form solution of the model). We have several data with known true positives and true negatives where it currently performing very well. I will definitely need to dig into the literature and hope to get some inspiration for my modeling of $\mu$ and hope I can at least come close to my current performance. Again, thank you and I must say your work is very impressive and has been very inspirational.

Comment: True positives and true negatives in the sense that the means should (or should not) be different by experimental design.